# Delete a variable number of records by a chronological order

Tags: sql-server-2012

Our developers have been using a cursor within a stored procedure to delete old password history.  The number of records to delete is being passed by variable.

```
DECLARE hist_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT history_nr   FROM usr_pwd_hist   WHERE usr_id = @usr_id
    ORDER BY    history_nr ASC

OPEN hist_cursor

WHILE @to_delete > 0
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM hist_cursor INTO @hist_val

    DELETE FROM usr_pwd_hist WHERE CURRENT OF hist_cursor

    SET @to_delete = @to_delete-1
END

CLOSE hist_cursor; 
DEALLOCATE hist_cursor;
```

I would like to replace this with a set based approach.  I can't do a simple top statement because the number of records to delete is a variable.  I can't use a top with a variable without dynamic sql and by policy we don't allow dynamic sql in production.

I'm considering this approach below but it makes me nervous as I know that Microsoft is planning on [changing the way ROWCOUNT affects return results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx).  By putting the delete targets in a subquery I should be ok with future SQL versions, but I'm still wondering if there is a better way to delete a variable number of records by a chronological order.

```
SET ROWCOUNT @to_delete;  /* limit records to be deleted */
DELETE FROM usr_pwd_hist WHERE history_nr IN
(
    SELECT history_nr 
    FROM usr_pwd_hist
    WHERE usr_id = @usr_id
    ORDER BY history_nr ASC  
);
SET ROWCOUNT 0;  /* return rowcount to default setting */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** use `TOP` with a variable. You just need to put it in parentheses.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT TOP (@to_delete) *
         FROM   usr_pwd_hist
         WHERE  usr_id = @usr_id
         ORDER  BY history_nr ASC)
DELETE FROM T;
```

Comment: Apparantly I didn't get the memo about using parenthesis.  Thank you SQL2005.  Awesome.

Comment: Also, I was trying to get around deprecation with the sub select but it's a nil issue now.  Thanks again.

Comment: `@RThomas - Yes I deleted the bit about deprecation as I saw you had already mentioned this and was aware of it.